# How to make Azure function trigger only for files, not for folders?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

I have a Azure Function set up like this.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "identifier.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "blob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "customers/{blob}",
      "connection": "DL_GEN2_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

The problem that I have is that the function triggers for folders as well as files, that are created in the blob storage.

Can one specify that it only triggers for files an not for folders?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested. The problem that I had was that folders would throw errors when triggering the Azure function, because it was an unknown data type to the function. My current solution is to check the size of the blob.

```
def main(blob: func.InputStream):

    if blob.length is None:
        logging.info("The blob has no data in it.")
        logging.info("The blob is most likely a folder.")
        return
```

This way it does at least not throw an error when creating folders in the blob storage.

Comment: blob.length produces None when I add CSV file to it. This is not working.

Comment: blob.length should only produce `None` if your input blob has 0 bytes. Are you sure your csv has data in it?

Comment: 11.22MB size of CSV. 100% sure.

Comment: How are you uploading a blob?
Certain clients create an empty blob first and then upload the data afterwards.

Comment: I'm uploading a CSV blob to container via azure portal. The file trigger azure function. azure function gets its name correct but length is None as I show you.

Comment: try to upload it with [Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/#overview)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you've got is that `{blob}` can't discern between folder or file as Azure Storage Blobs have no concept of directories. A directory in this sense is just part of the blob name.

You could filter on the blob name if a prefix is added to the file on upload but you're quite limited if you have no control over that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python#blob-name-patterns

Comment: yes, I thought about that, its unfortunate that this seems to be the only way

Comment: I suppose the other alternative would be to consider how often a new "directory" would be created within the blob container and have your trigger as `"path": "input/{blobname}.{blobextension}",` and handle the error in that a directory wouldn't have a `blobextension`. It won't let you create a "directory" in the portal which contains a period but it will in something like storage explorer `https://teststorageacc9.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/folder1.folder2/parameters.json` which I'm not sure if it would be caught by the trigger `blobextension`.